# How to make iframe work with webcam? [p5 & tensorflow.js]

Tags: javascript, iframe, p5.js, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to carry this p5 sketch I've done on the fabulous p5js web editor to a Wordpress page with iframe but it is not working.

This is the actual thing:
https://editor.p5js.org/ailgun/full/ry6qqlZ-4

This is iframe embed code;

```
<iframe src="https://editor.p5js.org/ailgun/embed/ry6qqlZ-4"></iframe>
```

I'm guessing the problem lies with the webcam cause other sketches like this work.

```
<iframe src="https://editor.p5js.org/embed/B1j5yC2vQ"></iframe>
```

It's also using another .js libraries like tensorflow.js and ml5js. Is it possible that they are causing problems as well?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Check out your browser's [developer tools](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) for errors. Try to isolate your problem: get a simple example working, then add one thing at a time until you can reproduce your problem in a [mcve]. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks very much. It kinda gave a hint:
(p5.dom.min.js:1 [Deprecation] getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See 'url here' for more details.)

As it has to ask the user to allow the webcam, it just seems to stuck on that. Still not sure how to fix tho.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add 'allow' attributes to the iframe element? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Attributes

I use ml5js in iframes without a problem accessing the camera or microphone.

Comment: Yes, in fact this is the entire iframe tag, I'm trying on a Wordpress page - can it be the problem?
<iframe allow="camera" style="width: 640px; height: 360px; overflow: hidden;" src="https://editor.p5js.org/ailgun/embed/ry6qqlZ-4" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>